# calling vim with mpiexec says "Warning: Output is not to a terminal / Warning: Input is not from a terminal"

Tags: command-line, invocation, unix

My question is a bit technical.

For specific reason, I need to call vim after mpiexec.

Example :

```
mpiexec -n 1 vim mytext.txt
```

But this gives the following warning message:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal 
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

And then, vim does not behave naturally, my input commands are not well interpreted in the editor, and things are not as if I had done simply:

```
vim mytext.txt
```

Any idea on how to redirect correctly input/output from/to my launching terminal in order to be able to use vim after mpiexec ?

Actually, the final goal is to debug in parallel using gdb on a specific proc and to edit functions with vim editor from gdb.

Example :

```
mpiexec -s 1 myprog : gdb myprog
```

So I am starting my program "myprog" on two processes, using gdb on the second one (which is proc 1), and redirecting stdin to proc 1 (thanks to -s 1 [see mpiexec -help]).

But then, if I want to edit a function with vim editor in gdb, I will face the same problems :

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

A quick solution would be to start an xterm window, but I want to avoid that approach:

```
mpiexec myprog : xterm -e gdb myprog
```

Thanks for your help.

Here is my Linux distribution:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Comment: More details on what mpiexec is might help

Comment: mpiexec alllows to run a program in parallel. I am using the mpiexec embedded in the Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2021.2 Build 20210302 (id: f4f7c92cd). Documentation can be found here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-reference-linux/top/command-reference/mpiexec-hydra.html                             
Intel® MPI Library is a multifabric message-passing library that implements the open-source MPICH specification (see  https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man1/mpiexec.1.php )